# Broken constraints in the cell

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I need to show some UIView in my cell, but size of this UIView (`backView`) is different for each cell. So I need to change the height of this cell also.

I'm trying to change height and width of this `backView` in runtime, but all that I'm getting is a bunch of Autolayout errors like that:

> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint...

I created SimpleTextCell class for this cell, and its init looks like that:

```
self.backView = UIView()
self.backView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.backView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
self.backView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
self.contentView.addSubview(backView)

let constraintBackViewTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: backView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .topMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -5)
let constraintBackViewBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: backView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .bottomMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 5)
let constraintBackViewLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: backView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .leftMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
constraintBackHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: backView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: superHeight)
constraintBackWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: backView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: superWidth)

self.contentView.addConstraints([constraintBackViewTop, constraintBackViewBottom, constraintBackViewLeft, constraintBackHeight, constraintBackWidth])
```

`superHeight` and `superWidth` are just some default values here.

my `cellForRowAt` function is like that:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "simpleTextCell", for: indexPath) as! SimpleTextCell

cell.selectionStyle = .none
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
cell.constraintBackHeight.constant = 100
cell.constraintBackWidth.constant = 200
cell.updateConstraints()
```

And it doesn't work at all. I'm having errors (like that I've mentioned earlier), and although the height of my cell is kinda right, my `backView` is invisible because width of `backView.frame` is zero (I don't have a clue why) and the height of `backView` is 100 (the same). It seems that my new constraints are ignored.

I've tried to set priority for these constraints in `cellForRowAt`:

```
cell.constraintBackHeight.priority = UILayoutPriority.init(rawValue: 999)
```

The result is run-time error.

I've tried to overcome this error by something like this:

```
cell.constraintBackHeight.isActive = false
cell.constraintBackHeight.priority = UILayoutPriority.init(rawValue: 999)
cell.constraintBackHeight.isActive = true
```

but it doesn't work either.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not just make a custom cell that resizes to its contents? Your approach of setting and updating constraints in the data source itself is a bad idea.

Comment: This backView is quite complicated actually because it contains several UILabels (I don't know their number or size beforehand so I can't create constraints for them in cell class). So I have to calculate the height of the container (backView) in cellForRowAt and update constraints (height and width) for the container.

I have a feeling that this is not an optimal solution but right now it's the best one I can think of. If you have another one, I'd be very glad to hear that, thanks.

Comment: First, you don't need to make a one-size-fits-all cell especially if it's polluted with observers and constraint changes at runtime. Don't be afraid to make multiple cells that cater to different configurations and dequeue the right ones at the data source. The data source should be as lean as possible because it is called a lot and bloating it will hinder performance and consume memory. Consider combining labels, if you have to. But when you anchor the subviews of a cell to the cell's edges, the cell becomes self-sizing. So come up with a clever way to make this work in your favor.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I'm using several custom cells in this table but I believe it'd be too much if I created different classes for cells with 2 UILabels, 3 UILabels etc (unfortunately I don't want to combine these labels). The cell in question is self-sizing, the problem I had was about inside view that is dictating the height of the cell but could be narrower than the cell. Anyway, thanks, I'll think about this solution once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
 constraintBackHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: backView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: superHeight)
 constraintBackWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: backView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: superWidth)
```

you're setting 2 height constraints , it may be you just copied to make as a width and forget to change it to `.width`

Comment: Thanks, you saved me. I'm still getting autolayout errors, but it works!